# Python multithreading not able to handle signal calls from modules

Tags: python, multithreading, nlp, httpserver

I am using `ThreadingMixIn` HTTP server told [here](http://doughellmann.com/2007/12/pymotw-basehttpserver.html) to make a HTTP server.

```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn
import threading

class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        /* DO NLP ANALYSIS USING TOPIA MODULE HERE , WHICH CALLS SIGALRM TO MAKE ITS OWN TIMEOUT */
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        message =  threading.currentThread().getName()
        self.wfile.write(message)
        self.wfile.write('\n')
        return

class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
"""Handle requests in a separate thread."""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = ThreadedHTTPServer(('localhost', 8080), Handler)
    print 'Starting server, use  to stop'
    server.serve_forever()
```

On a request to the HTTP server , it uses topia ( a python NLP package) to do some NLP stuff. Now Inside the topia termextract module , its using SIGALRM to apply timeout on processing time.

But i am seeing the following error -

```
  File "/home/vineeth/engine/repo/Engine-Developer/python/NLPServer/KeyTermExtractor.py", line 49, in getKeyTerms
    extracted = self.extractor(text)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/topia.termextract-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/topia/termextract/extract.py", line 118, in __call__
    split, terms = self.tagger(text)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/topia.termextract-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/topia/termextract/tag.py", line 182, in __call__
    split, terms = self.tokenize(text)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/topia.termextract-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/topia/termextract/tag.py", line 143, in tokenize
    match = slow_match(term)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/topia.termextract-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/topia/termextract/timeout.py", line 20, in new_f
    old = signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
```

Does this means that python can't in no way handle signal calls from a thread.
Does this means none of the packages which uses SIGNAL somewhere cant be executed in parallel threading ?

Answer (score 0):

> Does this means that python can't in no way handle signal calls from a
>   thread.

In short: yes.

The documentation states:

> Some care must be taken if both signals and threads are used in the
>   same program. The fundamental thing to remember in using signals and
>   threads simultaneously is: always perform signal() operations in the
>   main thread of execution.

See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/signal.html) for more information.

Comment: Is there any work around or something that can be done here. I want to use a module so badly and i need to use threading too.